# Facing a Ubuntu System error

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 installed system.Everything was working well all this while until I have been facing serious errors.Firstly the System sets up quiet slowly after I log in. Secondly the default themes wont set up. After I execute palimpsest under root privileges I cannot access any folders, clicking at root / does nothing. However at the terminal a error appears:

```
(nautilus:6243): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.nautilus.preferences' is not installed
```

I have gone through many of the posts online but none have helped.

well any help provided would be greatly appreciated

User

Comment: It would help if you explain what you have tried, so you don't get answers you don't need.

Comment: Open the terminal and run the command `nautilus`. The `palimpsest` command will open the Disk Utility that graphically displays your disks and partitions.